# Quickest way to format a disk with Linux?

Tags: linux, formatting, sd-card, dd, fdisk

It's for a bash/shell script. Basically, I want to format, or erase a USB (or SD) storage device; with a single command line.

I was going to use `fdisk`, but it seems to require user interaction where I want automation.

So then I decided to try zeroing it out with:
`dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/<target disk>`;
but it only seems to zero 2.0 GB of vacant, or unused disk space.

---

```
root@linux:~# dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/mmcblk0
dd: writing to '/dev/mmcblk0': No space left on device
3842249+0 records in
3842249+0 records out
1967230976 bytes (2.0 GB, 1.8 GiB) copied, 2.9054 s, 677 MB/s
```

---

Ideally, I'm talking about re-formatting any removable storage device, and/or prepping it to be imaged with an `.iso` image file (via `dd`).

Re-formatting won't *always* be required, but it also erases data; and clearing the device of any stored data probably ought to be the default behaviour / standard procedure, for this kind of thing anyway.

Comment: Do you want to format as in "zero out every sector", or format as in "create a blank filesystem"? Not that _either_ is necessary at all, since writing an image via dd already overwrites everything _anyway_...

Comment: @grawity Does it really? I didn't know that. I thought it was necessary to wipe the disk clean before imaging. But to answer your question; I would have liked to provide the option to the user, and let them decide on a case by case basis. In other words, I suppose the answer is: *both*. I would really appreciate it, cheers.

Comment: Yes it does – well, not the _whole_ drive but only as much data as the ISO itself occupies – but regardless, by dd'ing an image to `/dev/sdb` or such you completely clobber the partition table, the bootloader, the partitions and filesystems, etc. Your 8 GB flash drive ends up having e.g. one 700 MB partition (or whatever the ISO itself had) and 7.3 GB "unpartitioned space" which the OS doesn't even look at.

Comment: @grawity Not sure exactly how or why but, it literally just melted my SD card.

Comment: Sounds like a bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, this depends on

1. your definition of 'formatting' a drive;
2. the type of that drive.

---

"Format" might be one of the most confusing terms in consumer tech, really. Even your post already confuses two or three different actions...

Normally it covers three levels:

1. Preparing the media itself (e.g. writing sector markers to a HDD) – nowadays usually done by the factory, but at least in IBM PC days it could be done by the PC itself. This is often called "low-level formatting".
2. Writing a partition table (either blank or with some partitions) to the first few sectors of the disk – this is what `fdisk` does.
3. Writing a blank filesystem into each partition – this is what `format c:` or `mkfs` do. This used to be called "high-level formatting".

Except some people call step #2 "low-level format" now that there's no #1 anymore. And sometimes people call erasing the whole disk "formatting" even though it doesn't write anything with an *actual* format in there. Sometimes people call reinstalling Windows "formatting" even if all the files are left untouched.

---

Anyway, the rest of the answer depends on the *result* you want:

- If you want the disk to be completely blank (e.g. nothing that a data recovery app could possibly find), you have two options: discarding or manual erasing.

  The "discard" feature is called TRIM in SSDs and also supported by SD cards – it tells the disk itself to throw away all data. On Linux, the **`blkdiscard`** tool can be used for this purpose – specify a device and within seconds it's empty. (Tools like `mkfs.ext4` will also automatically discard the partition's contents before writing the new filesystem into it.)

  If the disk doesn't support discard – e.g. if it's a magnetic HDD, or if it's a USB flash drive whose Mass Storage interface doesn't *understand* this command – then your only other option is manually blanking out each and every sector, i.e. filling it with `/dev/zero` as you've already done.

  While discard usually takes only a few seconds, manual zero-filling cannot go any faster than the disk itself can accept writes (after all, you *are* writing a lot of data).
- If you don't care about residual data, but merely want the *OS* to see an empty disk, you can just blank out the area where *partition table* resides. For MBR that's always sector 0, but don't forget that many disks use a GPT partition table.

  This is a very fast method since you only have to erase a few kilobytes at most. On Linux, the `wipefs` command will surgically make disk contents no longer recognizable to the OS. (By default the tool only prints out what it *would* erase – use the option `--all` to make it actually do it.)

Eitehr way, now you have a disk that the OS considers to be empty.

- If you want the erased disk to have some *partitions*, use partitioning tools like fdisk or parted. While regular fdisk is interactive, there are *plenty* of tools which can be easily scripted – `sfdisk`, `sgdisk`, `parted` are a few examples. Windows has `diskpart`.
- If you also want the partitions to have *filesystems*, use tools like `mkfs.ext4` or `mkfs.vfat` (equivalent to Windows' `format`).

---

Finally, as mentioned in the comments above: If you're planning to just write an image (an .iso file) to the disk, then you *don't need* to do any preparations at all.

Such image writing starts at sector 0, so it trashes everything that was on the disk previously (up to the size of the image). Whether it had partitions and files, or whether it was blank, *doesn't matter* – it simply gets overwritten with the image's *own* partitions and all.

Everything *beyond* the size of the image will be left as it was, but the OS won't care about it – since the image's partition table says there's no partition there. Though of course discarding or blanking the disk is still a good idea if you're going to give it to somebody else.

Comment: Yes, I think I'd rather shred all the old data, just in case. I'll include a function with a `read` & `if`, `then`, `else`; or `case` statement. That way the user can decide.